# Why doesn't X11 set the only monitor as primary by default?

Tags: x11, xrandr, i3, tray

I need this for i3 to get myself the system tray icons. Wouldn't it make sense to have my only laptop display as the primary one instead of none? Is the standard approach to fixing this just running `xrandr --output --primary` from the `~/.xprofile`?

Answer (score 1):

I run an equivalent `xrandr` command as part of my X session (`~/.xsession`).  Alternatively, you could configure X11 to set the output as primary, system-wide; `Option "Primary" "true"`