# X11 not setting primary monitor according to config file

Tags: x11, xorg, configuration, monitors

^_^

#### Synopsis

I want to specify my primary monitor using system-wide X11 configuration files, but my present configuration files don't seem to do anything! 0_0

#### My situation

I'm coming from the same place as this question here: [Why doesn't X11 set the only monitor as primary by default?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/565553/why-doesnt-x11-set-the-only-monitor-as-primary-by-default)

Namely, I need the only monitor I have connected to be recognized as my primary monitor so that my tray icons in i3 work.

That said, I don't want to solve this using using `xrandr`, because I'm trying to use as much as possible the same dotfiles on two different machines which have different hardware configurations.

Therefore, I would like to solve this using the system-wide X11 configuration files.

However, it doesn't seem to work as expected. :o

#### My present setup

At present I have no `xorg.conf` file, and I do have a `xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf`, the contents of which (following [this Arch Linux wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multihead#Configuration_using_xorg.conf)) are here:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "HDMI2"
    Option      "Primary" "true"
EndSection
```

In light of this configuration file, here is my `xrandr` output for a fresh X session:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP1 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1400x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

As you can see, despite having specified `HDMI2` in the configuration files as my primary monitor, `DP1` is set as the primary.

#### Stuff I've tried

I've verified that my configuration file is being processed by X11 by introducing typos and observing that X11 fails to launch due to errors.

I've tried placing the configuration file above in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` instead of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf`.

I've tried including the following in an attempt to specify the default primary monitor as not primary:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "DP1"
    Option      "Primary" "false"
EndSection
```

I've tried launching with the default `xorg.conf` generated by `X -configure` alongside my `10-monitor.conf`.

#### Miscellaneous information

```
$ uname -a
Linux cheesy-6600k 5.9.8-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue, 10 Nov 2020 22:44:11 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ lscpu | grep name
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6600K CPU @ 3.50GHz
```

Comment: (for some reason it keeps removing my "Hello" from first line of the message XD)

Comment: what is removing "Hello" from which message?

Comment: @jsotola my post began with "Hello ^_^" but after posting it, the "Hello" part disappeared :o (and after editing it in attempt to add it back, it did as well)

Comment: oh, ok ... no problem then, since it is irrelevant to the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm 9 month late, but I've just ran into this issue and fixed it.

In my case LightDM was the issue. On the config file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, the line 114

```
display-setup-script=xrandr ...
```

is sending an `xrandr` command upon launching the display manager. In there I specified the primary screen and which screen is left and right of which other screen.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to get X11 to consider my Monitor section without adding a `Layout` section and `Screen` sections which name my Monitor section was to name my Monitor section `"<default monitor>"`. i.e.

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "<default monitor>"
    #other stuff here.
EndSection
```

But this is documented nowhere! I found it out by looking in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

The `xorg.conf` config file generated by `Xorg --configure` has nothing to do with what your hardware is actually doing by default!

For example, my system with no `xorg.conf` automaticly uses the `radeon` driver even though the `xorg.conf.new` generated by `Xorg --configure` specifies the `amdgpu` driver.

There seems to be now way go get the `xorg.conf` that would represent the system automatically generated!